# Send JSON/XML/TXT/CSV files to ElasticSearch

Tags: json, http, ubuntu, curl, elasticsearch

I have been trying to send some data in various formats to ElasticSearch running on my computer.

I am running Ubuntu 17 (the latest release) and am unable to do so.

Here are the commands I'm using on Terminal:

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:9200/json/test/2' -d @json.json
```

I am in the correct directory where the files are. Here is the error I'm getting:

```
{"error":"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported","status":406}
```

I've searched online to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

You can do something like this :

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "user" : "kimchy",
    "post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
    "message" : "trying out Elasticsearch"
}
'
```

The reason your request wasn't passing because you didnt specify the Content-Type as JSON. Plus, you should use PUT and not POST :) I copied this request from this documentation : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html. Cheers.

Comment: Now I'm getting this from Terminal. 


{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "failed to parse"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "failed to parse",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "not_x_content_exception",
      "reason" : "Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: json_products.json

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: Thanks. So i learned from https://www.elastic.co/blog/strict-content-type-checking-for-elasticsearch-rest-requests this new addition enforcing `http.content_type.required` to be true starting from version 6.0.0

Answer (score 2):

The error you're seeing is due to the version of the Elastic Search being different. Before `-XPUT`, add `-H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

Here is an example:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPUT 127.0.0.1:9200/
```